# Accessing TextBox List ID

Tags: android

**SOLVED**

I have a text box inside an XML file called list_entry.xml. The code for the file is as such:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<TextView  
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"  
    android:id="@+id/list_entry_title"  
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"   
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"  
    android:paddingTop="1dip"  
    android:paddingBottom="1dip"  
    android:paddingLeft="5dip"  
    style="android:attr/listViewWhiteStyle" />
```

So it's not too complicated. My question is: how do you access the "list_entry_title" textbox? I keep getting crashes (NullPointerException) when I try to use list_entry as a textbox.

Comment: Can you show code, where your are getting NullPointerException?

Comment: post your activity code and stack trace.

Comment: Never mind, realized how dumb I was. For whatever reason, I was using "R.layout.list_entry_title" instead of "R.id.list_entry_title". It's all working now

Comment: What's proper procedure for this? Do I just delete the post or leave it here? Sorry, I'm new :/

Comment: You can post an answer to your own question, then mark it as correct.

Answer (score 0):

Turns out I made a dumb mistake; I used R.layout instead of R.id when trying to access the TextBoxes. Thanks to everyone who commented!